# Having trouble following a step in Calkin's derivation of invariance transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry

Working through Chapter V of Calkin's "Lagrangian and Hamiltonian Mechanics" book. In deriving invariant transformations for free particles, he writes:

[image]

[image]

I cannot see why/how the two equations

$$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial x'} = -m\frac{da}{dt}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial t} = (1/2)m(\frac{da}{dt})^2$$

imply that $\frac{d^2a}{dt^2} = 0$

I've tried differentiating both expressions wrt time and also various algebraic manipulations but can't derive the result.

Edit: Corrected sign in one of the equations I typed out.

Comment: Remember $a$ is a function of $t$ *only*. So what happens if you differentiate each of the two equations, one wrt $t$ and the other wrt $x'$? And what can you  say about how the resulting partial derivatives are related to each other?

Comment: Perfect hint. Got me to where I needed to go and confirmed with QMechanic's hint below.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$-m\ddot{a}~=~\frac{\partial (-m\dot{a})}{\partial t } ~=~\frac{\partial^2\Lambda}{\partial t \partial x^{\prime}}
~=~\frac{\partial^2\Lambda}{\partial x^{\prime}\partial t}~=~\frac{\partial (m\dot{a}^2/2)}{\partial x^{\prime}}~=~0.    $$

(The LHS of Calkin's 3rd equation presumably contains a typo: It should be without primes.)